# Flutter Web PWA Top Notch gets cut off

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, iphone-x

I want to create a PWA using Flutter web but on iPhone X Models the top notch gets cut off.

Expected:

[image: expected]

Actual:

[image: actual]

The code I used:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(CupertinoApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(child: Center(child: Text("PWA")))));
}
```

I tried changing the meta tag in the *index.html* to:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent"></meta>
```

But this does not support dark mode.
Does any one got a better idea to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your widget in safe area to prevent your app having such problems.

```
SafeArea(
   child: Text("PWA"),
 ),
```

Happy coding...

Comment: No unfortunately this does not resolve my issue for a PWA on iPhoneX. The Top Area still gets cut off.